# How to display mapMarkers eventhough lat and log is same for multiple records

Tags: apex, google-map

I am displaying the Accounts in google Maps with Latitude and longitude. But Most of the records has same latitude and logitude. If Suppose latitude and longitude is same for 10 records but in Maps only one record is displaying. Is it possible to display multple Markers eventhough latitude and longitude is same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. Simply keep appending 0.001 to the co-ordinates every time you pass it to addMarker functionality. It will show that in nearby region. Fine grain the value to 0.000** to what ever level of accuracy you want.